# Python Tkinter Entry storing variables for later

Tags: python, tkinter

i am pretty new to Tkinter, but how can i get what i entered for all of the Entry commands to save as a variable for later? Here is my code that the Entry exists. This program is designed to track progress, and work with integers, not floating points. Thanks

It then uses the variables stored for later use for other components, of which works.

```
  name = Tk()
  name.wm_title("Name")

  Label(name, text="                       First").grid(row=0, column=0)
  Label(name, text="                        Last").grid(row=0, column=2)
  Label(name, text="             Starting height").grid(row=1, column=0)
  Label(name, text="                  Now height").grid(row=1, column=2)
  Label(name, text="                Starting Age").grid(row=2, column=0)
  Label(name, text="                     Now Age").grid(row=2, column=2)
  Label(name, text="        Starting Bench Press").grid(row=3, column=0)
  Label(name, text="   Personal best Bench press").grid(row=3, column=2)
  Label(name, text="     Starting Weighted Squat").grid(row=4, column=0)
  Label(name, text="Personal best weighted squat").grid(row=4, column=2)
  Label(name, text="           Starting deadlift").grid(row=5, column=0)
  Label(name, text="      Personal best deadlift").grid(row=5, column=2)
  Label(name, text="     Starting shoulder press").grid(row=6, column=0)
  Label(name, text="Personal best shoulder press").grid(row=6, column=2)
  Label(name, text="          Starting leg press").grid(row=7, column=0)
  Label(name, text="     Personal best leg press").grid(row=7, column=2)
  Label(name, text="       Starting lat pulldown").grid(row=8, column=0)
  Label(name, text="  Personal best lat pulldown").grid(row=8, column=2)


  first                    = Entry(name)
  last                     = Entry(name)
  starting_height          = Entry(name)
  Now_height               = Entry(name)
  Start_age                = Entry(name)
  Now_age                  = Entry(name)
  Start_Bench_Press        = Entry(name)
  Heaviest_Bench_Press     = Entry(name)
  Start_Weight_Squat       = Entry(name)
  Heaviest_Weight_Squat    = Entry(name)
  Start_deadlift           = Entry(name)
  Heaviest_deadlift        = Entry(name)
  Start_Shoulder_Press     = Entry(name)
  Heaviest_Shoulder_Press  = Entry(name)
  Start_Leg_Press          = Entry(name)
  Heaviest_Leg_Press       = Entry(name)
  Start_Lat_Pulldown       = Entry(name)
  Heaviest_Lat_Pulldown    = Entry(name)

  first.grid                   (row=0, column=1)
  last.grid                    (row=0, column=3)
  Starting_height.grid         (row=1, column=1)
  Now_height.grid              (row=1, column=3)
  Start_age.grid               (row=2, column=1)
  Now_age.grid                 (row=2, column=3)
  Start_Bench_Press.grid       (row=3, column=1)
  Heaviest_Bench_Press.grid    (row=3, column=3)
  Start_Weight_Squat.grid      (row=4, column=1)
  Heaviest_Weight_Squat.grid   (row=4, column=3)
  Start_deadlift.grid          (row=5, column=1)
  Heaviest_deadlift.grid       (row=5, column=3)
  Start_Shoulder_Press.grid    (row=6, column=1)
  Heaviest_Shoulder_Press.grid (row=6, column=3)
  Start_Leg_Press.grid         (row=7, column=1)
  Heaviest_Leg_Press.grid      (row=7, column=3)
  Start_Lat_Pulldown.grid      (row=8, column=1)
  Heaviest_Lat_Pulldown.grid   (row=8, column=3)


  Button(name, text='Quit', command=name.destroy).grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)

  name.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't forget to include the import statements to make your code runnable. It's especially important for `tkinter` as it indicates which python version you are using if you don't explicitly state that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using `IntVar` to save the value from an `Entry` widget.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

name = Tk()
name.wm_title("Name")

Label(name, text="sFirst").grid(row=0, column=0)

firstsv = IntVar()
first = Entry(name, textvariable=firstsv)

first.grid(row=0, column=1)

b1 = Button(name, text='Show', command=lambda: messagebox.showinfo("hi", firstsv.get()))
b1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)

name.mainloop()

# use after loop
print('firstsv = %d' % firstsv.get())
```

This is python 3 code. If you are using python 2 (as many beginners seem to be still be doing), it's left as an exercise to convert the code.

Comment: Hello, to try and close the question, i need an integer instead of a variable.I also need to be able to call the variables later in the program, outside of the loop. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated it to use `IntVar` instead of `StringVar` and the variable remains valid after the loop exits. You can assign the result of the `get` method to get it as a normal integer.